# Return all products from left table and results from rating table whether a given user rated them or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 332 products in a selection table and would like to return exactly 332 results. Each product has been rated or not by a given user in the matching table. These are the results from two tables using the following query

```
SELECT a.product_id,a.brand,b.user_id,b.rating,b.comment
FROM selection a
LEFT JOIN matching b ON a.product_id = b.product_id

product_id brand    user_id rating  comment
1          A & P      30    4.5       NULL
1          A & P      30    4.5       NULL
1          A & P      52    1         NULL
2          A & W      1     3         good flavor
2          A & W      24    5         NULL
```

I want to return all the products with a rating and comment where user_id = 1 and then the remaining products where user 1 did not rate or comment on the product. I have tried

```
WHERE user_id = 1 OR 
user_id <> 1 AND rating ID NULL and comment IS NULL
```

This will just return  the same as `WHERE user_id = 1`. I have also tried `GROUP BY product_id` This returns the correct number of results but not all of the user's ratings or comments were controlled by this alone. Is there a way to define the user that it will select when returning the grouped results? Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try using 'GROUP BY Comment' or 'GROUP BY Rating' instead of product_id

Comment: `GROUP BY comment` and `GROUP BY` rating did not return each product. For example, `GROUP BY comment` only returned one `NULL` result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant for the WHERE statement to include two separate conditions you need to surround the second statement in parenthesis; otherwise SQL would treat each operator as its own condition:

```
WHERE user_id = 1 OR 
(user_id <> 1 AND rating ID NULL and comment IS NULL)
```